# Outline/stroke around transparent-background PNG in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I was wondering if there is a way to expand a fill, outset a shadow or something, around a PNG with transparent background.

Right now I am using Fill + Simple Choker to expand the contour + CC Composite to bring it to the bottom, and sort of works, but I can expand the outline only a few pixels, like less than 100. Ideally, I'd like to animate it, so I can't just add the outline in Photoshop!

Is there an alternative way to do that? Thank you in advance.

[image: outline around opaque pixels]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Layer--> Auto-trace to tracing around the alpha. It will generate a mask which you can then expand.

Or you could use a Layer Style to get a similar effect with a drop shadow or glow effect.